# Convert SQL select into PHP string variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to select the latest element in the column with maximum ID and then convert it into string variable. The table is a standard WordPress `wp_postmeta` with elements: `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`. I want to fetch the latest `post_id` (with the highest number) and then use it as a variable string to use in latter operations.

The code I got so far is:

```
$order = mysql_query('SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM wp_postmeta')
```

But of course it isn't complete. I just want to have $order that corresponds with the latest order ID in the database to inject some additional info after checkout.

Like, if there is post_id in the database with a value of 2700 and it is the latest `post_id` available with the highest ID number, then I would like `$order` to be excactly 2700.

A great addition would be also to get `$order2`, which has a value of `$order + 1` - just in case.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*()` functions any more as they were deprecated and removed from PHP as of version 7. Use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil I think it's superfluous to point that out. He didn't bother to even complete the simplest tutorial on PHP and its integration with mysql, or read the documentation, even the old one, on this. It's like me buying a car then calling customer support to ask which seat I am supposed to be driving on.

Comment: Changed to mysqli, thanks for this. I found this on StackExchange and pasted without much thought, changing the database only.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
$result= mysql_query('SELECT MAX(post_id) order FROM wp_postmeta');
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$order= $res["order"];
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: I know this isn't most liked answer, but honestly this just needs to work for a brief period of time so the the external app can inject additional data to the database for the last order processed. The application will be scrapped in a week and I already prepared most of the code, just need this $order to work. How do I insert this into SQL query later? Will $_POST("order") work or do I need to get additional variable?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in WordPress you should never use `mysql_query` but the `$wpdb` class: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

What you probably want is something like the following:

```
$wpdb->get_row('SELECT *,MAX(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type="offer" GROUP BY ID);
```

In general the WordPress way to find posts is `meta_query` - do not overcomplicate things:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Thanks for this and I'm sure it's the best solution. However, the app handling this is external and I have insufficient programming skills to integrate it with WP. I just need the process to work and it can be the quickiest and dirtiest way possible. The application will be scrapped next week anyway.